# Overriding AnalogClock in Android

Tags: java, android

I want to create an AnalogClock that can display a preset time, given as a parameter.

And I want to draw between the background and the hands. I want to paint the area between the minute-hand and location of the hour-hand at a preset future time. This is to let the user see how much time remains for the current activity.

I thought that I could take the AnalogClock object and extend that. However, when I create a new function that is essentially a copy of one of the old ones, I get errors on the com.android.internal.R.styleable.AnalogClock* objects: "com.android.internal.R cannot be resolved"

How can I import these objects? I've read something about declare-styleable, but I cannot figure out how to apply that to my situation. (Sorry, I'm really a Java n00b)

For instance, the internal objects refer to several graphical things, such as dials, hour_hand and minute_hands.

Here's my code: http://pastie.org/713276

Any help is very much appreciated, I am stuck after hours of Google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Set time with custom android AnalogClock from its original class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16786441/set-time-with-custom-android-analogclock-from-original-analogclock-class/16804506#16804506) Please have a look at my solution. You can use it to display a custom analog clock in a application and set time that you want in it.

Comment: Thanks, but it has been four years... :)

Comment: Well information never dies, I didn't see the date :P Nice one!

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://nexsoftware.net/wp/2009/07/29/tutorial-creating-a-custom-analogclock-widget/) is an tutorial for creating a custom Analog Clock. Shows some sample code, hope this is at least a start in the right direction.

Comment: Cool, can I use this also to display a custom clock within a program?

Comment: you might be able to, I know a little bit about Android but I cannot say for sure. You would probably have to make space for it inside of your AndroidManifest.xml file, like have a LinearLayout and display like a Button and then your Custom Clock

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing me in the right direction. I think this tutorial will get me through.. :)

Comment: Good luck, if you need anymore help just keep posting ;)