# Set time with custom android AnalogClock from its original class

Tags: java, android, time, widget, clock

I want to make a custom AnalogClock class using source code of AnalogClock by Android Open Source Project that is available in the internet.

I want to make the clock set the time that I want, not the current time. I didn't find a clear example on how to do it so maybe this post will be useful. After copying source code to new file, I get some errors. Below is the original source code of AnalogClock:

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2006 The Android Open Source Project
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package android.widget;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.text.format.Time;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.RemoteViews.RemoteView;

import java.util.TimeZone;

/**
 * This widget display an analogic clock with two hands for hours and
 * minutes.
 */
@RemoteView
public class AnalogClock extends View {
    private Time mCalendar;

    private Drawable mHourHand;
    private Drawable mMinuteHand;
    private Drawable mDial;

    private int mDialWidth;
    private int mDialHeight;

    private boolean mAttached;

    private final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private float mMinutes;
    private float mHour;
    private boolean mChanged;

    public AnalogClock(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public AnalogClock(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }
```

**!!Error mContext -> changed mContext to context (could I do that)?**

```
    public AnalogClock(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
                       int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        Resources r = mContext.getResources();
```

**!!Error com.android.internal.R cannot be resolved.**
I found a solution to this problem with

```
mDial = r.getDrawable(Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("clock_dial","drawable", "android"));
```

And same for other lines just changing name and either drawable or styleable.

vvvv----**But I still have a problem with the below code.**

```
        TypedArray a =
                context.obtainStyledAttributes(
                        attrs, com.android.internal.R.styleable.AnalogClock, defStyle, 0);
```

^^^^----**I don't have idea how to change it and make it work**

```
        mDial = a.getDrawable(com.android.internal.R.styleable.AnalogClock_dial);
        if (mDial == null) {
            mDial = r.getDrawable(com.android.internal.R.drawable.clock_dial);
        }

        mHourHand = a.getDrawable(com.android.internal.R.styleable.AnalogClock_hand_hour);
        if (mHourHand == null) {
            mHourHand = r.getDrawable(com.android.internal.R.drawable.clock_hand_hour);
        }

        mMinuteHand = a.getDrawable(com.android.internal.R.styleable.AnalogClock_hand_minute);
        if (mMinuteHand == null) {
            mMinuteHand = r.getDrawable(com.android.internal.R.drawable.clock_hand_minute);
        }

        mCalendar = new Time();

        mDialWidth = mDial.getIntrinsicWidth();
        mDialHeight = mDial.getIntrinsicHeight();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();

        if (!mAttached) {
            mAttached = true;
            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();

            filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK);
            filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIME_CHANGED);
            filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED);

            getContext().registerReceiver(mIntentReceiver, filter, null, mHandler);
        }

        // NOTE: It's safe to do these after registering the receiver since the receiver always runs
        // in the main thread, therefore the receiver can't run before this method returns.

        // The time zone may have changed while the receiver wasn't registered, so update the Time
        mCalendar = new Time();

        // Make sure we update to the current time
        onTimeChanged();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
        super.onDetachedFromWindow();
        if (mAttached) {
            getContext().unregisterReceiver(mIntentReceiver);
            mAttached = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

        int widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
        int widthSize =  MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        int heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
        int heightSize =  MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

        float hScale = 1.0f;
        float vScale = 1.0f;

        if (widthMode != MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED && widthSize < mDialWidth) {
            hScale = (float) widthSize / (float) mDialWidth;
        }

        if (heightMode != MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED && heightSize < mDialHeight) {
            vScale = (float )heightSize / (float) mDialHeight;
        }

        float scale = Math.min(hScale, vScale);

        setMeasuredDimension(resolveSize((int) (mDialWidth * scale), widthMeasureSpec),
                resolveSize((int) (mDialHeight * scale), heightMeasureSpec));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        mChanged = true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        boolean changed = mChanged;
        if (changed) {
            mChanged = false;
        }
```

**!!!Error - where does mRight, mLeft, mBotton, mTop come from? It is not declared in this file**

```
        int availableWidth = mRight - mLeft;
        int availableHeight = mBottom - mTop;

        int x = availableWidth / 2;
        int y = availableHeight / 2;

        final Drawable dial = mDial;
        int w = dial.getIntrinsicWidth();
        int h = dial.getIntrinsicHeight();

        boolean scaled = false;

        if (availableWidth < w || availableHeight < h) {
            scaled = true;
            float scale = Math.min((float) availableWidth / (float) w,
                                   (float) availableHeight / (float) h);
            canvas.save();
            canvas.scale(scale, scale, x, y);
        }

        if (changed) {
            dial.setBounds(x - (w / 2), y - (h / 2), x + (w / 2), y + (h / 2));
        }
        dial.draw(canvas);

        canvas.save();
        canvas.rotate(mHour / 12.0f * 360.0f, x, y);
        final Drawable hourHand = mHourHand;
        if (changed) {
            w = hourHand.getIntrinsicWidth();
            h = hourHand.getIntrinsicHeight();
            hourHand.setBounds(x - (w / 2), y - (h / 2), x + (w / 2), y + (h / 2));
        }
        hourHand.draw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();

        canvas.save();
        canvas.rotate(mMinutes / 60.0f * 360.0f, x, y);

        final Drawable minuteHand = mMinuteHand;
        if (changed) {
            w = minuteHand.getIntrinsicWidth();
            h = minuteHand.getIntrinsicHeight();
            minuteHand.setBounds(x - (w / 2), y - (h / 2), x + (w / 2), y + (h / 2));
        }
        minuteHand.draw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();

        if (scaled) {
            canvas.restore();
        }
    }

    private void onTimeChanged() {
        mCalendar.setToNow();

        int hour = mCalendar.hour;
        int minute = mCalendar.minute;
        int second = mCalendar.second;

        mMinutes = minute + second / 60.0f;
        mHour = hour + mMinutes / 60.0f;
        mChanged = true;
    }

    private final BroadcastReceiver mIntentReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED)) {
                String tz = intent.getStringExtra("time-zone");
                mCalendar = new Time(TimeZone.getTimeZone(tz).getID());
            }

            onTimeChanged();

            invalidate();
        }
    };
}
```

Can anyone tell me:

1. How can I make this class work like a normal AnalogClock
2. How can I write a method inside this class that will apply time that I will provide to it?

Comment: what part of that heap of code is causing you trouble?

Comment: @MarcoForberg it is shown in my post above marked by !!!Error

Comment: "where does mRight, mLeft, mBotton, mTop come from? It is not declared in this file" since this is your class you should know. I assume these values are declared in a super class like `View`

Comment: This is not my class, I got it from http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/widget/AnalogClock.java It is a source code for AnalogClock from Android Open Source Project

Comment: what ide are you using. there should be an option that takes you to the definition of a variable. In eclipse it is ctrl+click on the variable.

Comment: There is no definition of that variable in this file that is why I get an error...

Comment: i know that is why i did not say "this file"

Comment: Also I am not sure where I should physically put that class file. When I put it in my project, I get a package error, because my package name is not android.widget. Any idea about TypedArray a =
                context.obtainStyledAttributes(
                        attrs, com.android.internal.R.styleable.AnalogClock, defStyle, 0);?

Comment: there are two ways concerning that package declaration: 1. create a package `android.widget` 2. change the package declaration to match your actual package

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30792/discussion-between-marek-and-marco-forberg)

Comment: @Marek, do you have the source code of the custom analog clock. I have done as per the acepted solution of this question, but I am unable to display the analog clock

Comment: I don't have it anymore

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Working custom MyAnalogClock with setTime() method.**

After spending some time I finally managed to solve the problem.
I hope it will be useful for someone.
You can set time simply by calling setTime(hours, minutes, seconds) method.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.text.format.Time;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.RemoteViews.RemoteView;

/**
 * This widget display an analogic clock with two hands for hours and
 * minutes.
 */
@RemoteView
public class MyAnalogClock extends View {

    private Drawable mHourHand;
    private Drawable mMinuteHand;
    private Drawable mSecondHand;
    private Drawable mDial;

    private int mDialWidth;
    private int mDialHeight;

    private float mSeconds;
    private float mMinutes;
    private float mHour;

    Context mContext;

    public MyAnalogClock(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyAnalogClock(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public MyAnalogClock(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
                       int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        Resources r = context.getResources();
        TypedArray a =
                context.obtainStyledAttributes(
                        attrs, R.styleable.AnalogClock, defStyle, 0);
        mContext=context;
       // mDial = a.getDrawable(com.android.internal.R.styleable.AnalogClock_dial);
       // if (mDial == null) {
            mDial = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.clock_dial);
       // }

      //  mHourHand = a.getDrawable(com.android.internal.R.styleable.AnalogClock_hand_hour);
      //  if (mHourHand == null) {
            mHourHand = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.clock_hour);
      //  }

     //   mMinuteHand = a.getDrawable(com.android.internal.R.styleable.AnalogClock_hand_minute);
     //   if (mMinuteHand == null) {
            mMinuteHand = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.clock_minute);
            mSecondHand = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.clockgoog_minute);
     //   }

        mDialWidth = mDial.getIntrinsicWidth();
        mDialHeight = mDial.getIntrinsicHeight();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

        int widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
        int widthSize =  MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        int heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
        int heightSize =  MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

        float hScale = 1.0f;
        float vScale = 1.0f;

        if (widthMode != MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED && widthSize < mDialWidth) {
            hScale = (float) widthSize / (float) mDialWidth;
        }

        if (heightMode != MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED && heightSize < mDialHeight) {
            vScale = (float )heightSize / (float) mDialHeight;
        }

        float scale = Math.min(hScale, vScale);

        setMeasuredDimension(resolveSize((int) (mDialWidth * scale), widthMeasureSpec),
                resolveSize((int) (mDialHeight * scale), heightMeasureSpec));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        //Here you can set the size of your clock
        int availableWidth = 70;
        int availableHeight = 70;

        //Actual size
        int x = availableWidth / 2;
        int y = availableHeight / 2;

        final Drawable dial = mDial;
        int w = dial.getIntrinsicWidth();
        int h = dial.getIntrinsicHeight();

        boolean scaled = false;

        if (availableWidth < w || availableHeight < h) {
            scaled = true;
            float scale = Math.min((float) availableWidth / (float) w,
                                   (float) availableHeight / (float) h);
            canvas.save();
            canvas.scale(scale, scale, x, y);
        }

        dial.setBounds(x - (w / 2), y - (h / 2), x + (w / 2), y + (h / 2));
        dial.draw(canvas);

        canvas.save();
        canvas.rotate(mHour / 12.0f * 360.0f, x, y);
        w = mHourHand.getIntrinsicWidth();
        h = mHourHand.getIntrinsicHeight();
        mHourHand.setBounds(x - (w / 2), y - (h / 2), x + (w / 2), y + (h / 2));
        mHourHand.draw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();

        canvas.save();
        canvas.rotate(mMinutes / 60.0f * 360.0f, x, y);
        w = mMinuteHand.getIntrinsicWidth();
        h = mMinuteHand.getIntrinsicHeight();
        mMinuteHand.setBounds(x - (w / 2), y - (h / 2), x + (w / 2), y + (h / 2));
        mMinuteHand.draw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();

        canvas.save();
        canvas.rotate(mSeconds, x, y);
        w = mSecondHand.getIntrinsicWidth();
        h = mSecondHand.getIntrinsicHeight();
        mSecondHand.setBounds(x - (w / 2), y - (h / 2), x + (w / 2), y + (h / 2));
        mSecondHand.draw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
        if (scaled) {
            canvas.restore();
        }
    }

    public void setTime(int hours, int minutes, int seconds)
    {
        mSeconds = 6.0f*seconds;
        mMinutes = minutes + seconds / 60.0f;
        mHour = hours + mMinutes / 60.0f;
    }
}
```

You should also put 4 drawable files in the drawable folder and create (or update) the attrs file in values folder with the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="AnalogClock">
        <attr name="dial" format="reference"/>
        <attr name="hand_hour" format="reference"/>
        <attr name="hand_minute" format="reference"/>
    </declare-styleable>
    </resources>
```

Comment: thanks for nice code, now my question is how to change the time on touch method(listener) or call the setTime() method.
Thanks in advance

Comment: IT depends on when you want time to be changed (you want it to be changed on touch?)

Comment: yes, when i will touch on hour's, minute's, second's drawable then time will be change..

Comment: when i will touch on hours drawable then it's location will change means change the time.
Eg. now my hr is 8 and i have touch on Hour's drawable  and drag on 9th postion then new time will be set 9'o clock..in our clock using setTime method.:)

Comment: Ah now I understand. You should use both the onTouch() method and setTime() method :)

Comment: how do you adjust the size of the view in the layout?

Answer (score 0):

```
//Here you can set the size of your clock
int availableWidth = 70;
int availableHeight = 70;
```

This is where you can change the size of the View.