# Android app display classic clock that allows user interaction

Tags: android, android-studio, clock, user-interaction, real-time-clock

I want to create an Analog clock in Android Studio. I have done so successfully to show the current time and run, however I cannot figure out how to allow the user to set the time.

I have implemented the methods from the link below to display the clock, in the ClockView method and to run it. https://www.ssaurel.com/blog/learn-to-draw-an-analog-clock-on-android-with-the-canvas-2d-api/

I want the user of the app to be able to manually input the time, press one button and the clock should display the time set by the user and then start running like a normal clock.
The changes I have done allows the clock to show the time set by the user but it does not run.

Please explain how I can implement it and perhaps with a documentation to understand why.

Comment: try to set the manual time in **drawHands(Canvas canvas)** method

Answer (score 0):

Refer this link as he found solution[Analog clock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16786441/set-time-with-custom-android-analogclock-from-its-original-class)

But he used different solution